# customer attribute taxvat value not saving to database (from frontend custom registration form)

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, customer-attribute

We setup 2 website/store. When we tried to create customer from a store (i.e. not main store). By using `customer/form_register` type form submission. customer created successfully but `taxvat` field not saving with customer information. All other required customer attributes `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` saving correctly but only `taxvat` attribute not saving.

Code for Load layout with `customer/form_register` block type :

```
<reference name = "content">
   <block type = "customer/form_register" name = "customer_form_register" template = "seller/seller.phtml">
      <action method = "setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
        <block type = "page/html_wrapper" name = "customer.form.register.fields.before" as = "form_fields_before" translate = "label">
           <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        </block>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Template File :

```
<form name="test-form1" id="my-custom-form1" action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl(); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl(); ?>" />
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label>First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Middle Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="middlename"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Tax/Vat Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="taxvat"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This problem also exist for `middlename`, `prefix`, `suffix` attribute.

All these attributes 'taxvat', 'middlename', 'prefix', 'suffix' are exist in default magento setup same like 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email' exist. the only difference is they are not required.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happened and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Share your controller code

Comment: If you have recently created `taxvat` attribute, just clear your cache and var/lock folder. Re-index your magento and try again.

Comment: taxvat is a magento attribute . I have only use there name in my form field  and I have clear cache. But my problem is not solve.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because those attributes you mentioned have `is_visible` set to `0` in the `customer_eav_attribute` table. They are saved with this value when they are created by the setup.

Before saving the customer data, in the controller (`Mage_Customer_AccountController`) the `_getCustomerErrors` function is called:

```
protected function _getCustomerErrors($customer)
{
    $errors = array();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getPost('create_address')) {
        $errors = $this->_getErrorsOnCustomerAddress($customer);
    }
    $customerForm = $this->_getCustomerForm($customer);
    $customerData = $customerForm->extractData($request);
    $customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);
    if ($customerErrors !== true) {
        $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
    } else {
        $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
        $customer->setPassword($request->getPost('password'));
        $customer->setConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
        $customerErrors = $customer->validate();
        if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
            $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Not all the data you submit from the form gets set on the customer model in order to be saved. The data is first extracted in `Mage_Customer_Model_Form` class, which extends `Mage_Eav_Model_Form`.
The first condition for the attribute data to be set on the customer model is that the specific attribute should be associated to submited form (you can check these in the `customer_form_attribute` table by filtering by `form_code` **customer_account_create**). This condition should be met for the attributes you mentioned since they are added to this form when they are created by the setup.
The second condition for the attribute data to be set on the customer model is to pass the validation in the `Mage_Eav_Model_Form::extractData` function:

```
public function extractData(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request, $scope = null, $scopeOnly = true)
{
    $data = array();
    foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
        if ($this->_isAttributeOmitted($attribute)) {
            continue;
        }
        $dataModel = $this->_getAttributeDataModel($attribute);
        $dataModel->setRequestScope($scope);
        $dataModel->setRequestScopeOnly($scopeOnly);
        $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $dataModel->extractValue($request);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The `_isAttributeOmitted` function will check the `is_visible` value:

```
protected function _isAttributeOmitted($attribute)
{
    if ($this->_ignoreInvisible && !$attribute->getIsVisible()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can check the `is_visible` values for those attribute by running this query on your database:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_eav_attribute c WHERE attribute_id IN (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code IN ('taxvat', 'middlename', 'prefix', 'suffix') AND entity_type_id=1
);
```

If the value for `is_visible` is `0` then you can change it to `1`.

If you are using Magento Enterprise then you can edit the customer attributes in **Customers -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Attributes**. If you set **Show on Frontend** to **Yes** then the customer attribute values should be saved correctly into the database.

Comment: Good answer @Marina. However, it would be best to do this in an upgrade script: `$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", 'taxvat');
$attribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$attribute->save();
`

Comment: Great suggestion, @Giel! If it's not Magento Enterprise, where you can edit this from admin, a setup script in a custom module would be the way to go. This way it's easier to deploy too.